# MVC is passing old text value to controller after edit

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller

I have a text field where the text is loaded from a viewmodel, then I want to change the text and send it to my controller. But after I edited the text, the controller received the old text value from my text field.

My View:

```
    @model Football_Insider.ViewModels.ArticleViewModel

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "EditArticle";
    }

<section id="breadcrumb">
    <div class="container">
        <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="active"></li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</section>

    @using (@Html.BeginForm("EditArticle", "Article", FormMethod.Post, new { 
    enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Article.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Article.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control col-md-12" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Article.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Article.Content, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-12" })
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Article.Content, new { @class = "form-control col-md-12", @rows = 20, @cols = 50 })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Article.Content, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    @Html.Hidden("articleId", Model.Article.ArticleId)
    @Html.Hidden("title", Model.Article.Title)
    @Html.Hidden("content", Model.Article.Content)

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Volgende" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is your controller code?

Comment: Why do you have an `EditorFor` *and* a `Hidden` for `Model.Article.Title`? (I'm assuming that's the text value you're referring to?)

Comment: You need to show your controller code (the answer you accepted is incorrect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `@Html.Hidden("content", Model.Article.Content)`
because it overrides your text area value

Comment: I know but how do is pass the edited value to my controller then?

Comment: `EditorFor` will handle that

Comment: Thank you guys this is what I was looking for :)

Comment: No it does not. The `DefaultModelBinder` binds the first name/value pair in the request and ignores subsequent values with the same name. In any case, the hidden inputs are for completely different properties - `content` (hidden input) vs `Article.Content` (textarea) - the 2nd being a property `Article` that is a complex object contain a property named `Article`)